# Getting AttributeError Message when trying to close a file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, attributeerror

I am using Python 3 to practice reading in files and using dictionaries. I am trying to close the file but am getting an error instead.

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'close'.
```

code:

```
try:
ifile = ("inputfile.txt", "r")
except IOError:
    print("Error opening file")
else:
    for line in ifile:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line or line[0] == "#":
            continue
        else:  
            data =line.split(" ") 
    mydict = {}

    for item in data:
        key = item[0] + item[-1]

        value = item[1:-1]
        mydict[key] = [value]
    print(mydict)
    ifile.close()
```

Why is this error happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is there only one line in the input file? Then the for-loop is irritating. Do you really want a list of lists in your dict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't opened the file ! you have just created a `tuple`,change the following  :

```
ifile = ("inputfile.txt", "r")
```

to :

```
ifile = open("inputfile.txt", "r")
```